# Change the initial visible location on Bing Map

Tags: javascript, bing

How can I change the initial location visible at the first load of a Bing Map?
By default I see that it is set to United States (see picture) and I want to set it to Eastern Europe (Romania).

[image]

Here is my code that loads the map:

```
var map = null;
var points = [];
var shapes = [];
var center = null;

function LoadMap(latitude, longitude, onMapLoaded) {
    map = new VEMap('theMap');
    options = new VEMapOptions();
    options.EnableBirdseye = false;

    // Makes the control bar less obtrusize.
    map.SetDashboardSize(VEDashboardSize.Small);

    if (onMapLoaded != null)
        map.onLoadMap = onMapLoaded;

    if (latitude != null && longitude != null) {
        center = new VELatLong(latitude, longitude);
    }

    map.LoadMap(center, null, null, null, null, null, null, options);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by adding an `else` condition:

```
else {
    center = new VELatLong(45.747806, 24.617061);
}
```